# how to getting the email verification link in Unit Test Laravel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am developing a Laravel application. I am doing unit testing to my application. Now I am having a trouble with testing the verification process.

What I am trying to do now is that I am registering a user, then test if the verification email is sent, then I will get the verification link for that registration, then I will do something with that link.

1. The first issue is that the email is not sent.
2. The second issue is that I do not know how to retrieve the
   verification email link?

This is my test

```
public function test_user_can_be_verified_and_redirected_based_on_role()
{
    Notification::fake();
    $user = $this->registerUser();
    Notification::assertSentTo($user, SendEmailVerificationNotification::class);

}

protected function registerUser()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->make();

    $this->post(route('register'), [
        'name' => $user->name,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => 'testing',
        'password_confirmation' => 'testing',
    ])->assertRedirect();

    return User::whereEmail($user->email)->first();
}
```

But the issue is that the notification is not sent even if it is sent when I register from the browser. I also like to retrieve the verification link and do something. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you also include your register function?

Comment: Just built in laravel register function

Comment: I have the same issue, the notification is not sent. I also had a problem where the user created by `registerUser` was not the one used in the test. I had to `$user = User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();` in the test. It may be useful

Comment: At first be sure that your User model implements 'MustVerifyEmail' interface then check if your register function has Registered event called: event(new Registered($user));

Answer (score 7):

Not a perfect solution but it does the trick, if somebody breaks this functionality somehow I'll know about it. :)

First overwrite the protected method `verificationUri` of the `VerifyEmail` notification and make it public

```
class EmailVerificationNotification extends VerifyEmail
{
    public function verificationUrl($notifiable) {
        return parent::verificationUrl($notifiable);
    }
}
```

Then use it to generate a link and assert against it..

```
    /** @test */
    public function an_user_can_verify_his_email_address()
    {
        $notification = new EmailVerificationNotification();

        $user = factory(User::class)->create(['email_verified_at' => null]);

        $uri = $notification->verificationUrl($user);

        $this->assertSame(null, $user->email_verified_at);

        $this->actingAs($user)->get($uri);

        $this->assertNotNull($user->email_verified_at);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you consider it as "not a perfect solution"? I see no problem with this.

Comment: dunno. because of the extension that actually does nothing except that it gives me access to the underling method?

Comment: Short and precise! thank you, here's a 50 rep bounty :)

Comment: arguably that laravel declares all functions as protected is inferior. I understand their thought

Answer (score 5):

A verification URL can be generated outside of the VerifyEmail notification easily by simply running:

```
    $verificationUrl = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
        'verification.verify',
        now()->addMinutes(60),
        ['id' => $user->id, 'hash' => sha1($user->email)]
    );
```

No need to make the `verificationUrl()` method public.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
public function testVerifyEmailValidatesUser(): void
{
    // VerifyEmail extends Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail in this example
    $notification = new VerifyEmail();
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    // New user should not has verified their email yet
    $this->assertFalse($user->hasVerifiedEmail());

    $mail = $notification->toMail($user);
    $uri = $mail->actionUrl;

    // Simulate clicking on the validation link
    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->get($uri);

    // User should have verified their email
    $this->assertTrue(User::find($user->id)->hasVerifiedEmail());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @florent is great, however for Laravel 5.7.29 I find that the new user created using the factory automatically has its email_verified_at flag set, so the first test - that the user is NOT yet verified - fails.

With the addition of an array to set `email_verified_at` to `null`, correct operation is observed:

```php
public function testVerifyEmailValidatesUser(): void
{
    // VerifyEmail extends Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail in this example
    $notification = new VerifyEmail();
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([ 'email_verified_at' => null ]);

    // New user should not has verified their email yet
    $this->assertFalse($user->hasVerifiedEmail());

    $mail = $notification->toMail($user);
    $uri = $mail->actionUrl;

    // Simulate clicking on the validation link
    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->get($uri);

    // User should have verified their email
    $this->assertTrue(User::find($user->id)->hasVerifiedEmail());
}
```